# Adding click event handlers recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, recursion

I have an element `#standardBox`

`#standardBox.click --> replaces itself with #newBox`

`#newBox.click --> replaces itself with #standardBox`

But this latest `#standardBox` has no click event listener. I want it to have an on click event listener and its subsequently created elements too. This is getting into a recursive loop, which I don't know how to address.

I'm using this for header with standard contents, which gets replaced by something intermediate/new contents, which again is to get back to standard contents ...

Thanks.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="standardBox"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    background: #C5CAE9;
}
#standardBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#newBox {
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    background: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#standardBox').click(function(){
   $('#container').html('<div id="newBox"></div>');
   // register event handler for new element created
    $('#newBox').click(function(){
        $('#container').html('<div id="standardBox"></div>');
        // but this #standardBox has no click event listener
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPLKLq

Comment: is this the same as using a 'tmp' variable, use stdBox to setup tempBox, lah-lah, and tmpBox -> newBox, lah-lah, newBox->stdBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the handler to the body instead like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#standardBox", function(){
    $('#container').html('<div id="newBox"></div>');
})
.on("click", "#newBox", function(){
    $('#container').html('<div id="standardBox"></div>');
});
```

This causes the body to listen for events that come from `#standardBox` and `#newBox`. Note that the `this` variable is still set to either the `#standardBox` or the `#newBox` element.

Comment: Why the `body`? The closest parent would be good enough and that's `#container`

Comment: The container may be removed and re-added at some point, and so this works around that case. But yes, if there's a guarantee that the container won't change feel free to add it there.  This just gives more flexibility, but any parent will do.

Comment: How can I convert this to vanilla javascript? el.addEventListener() does not accept other elements as parameters

Comment: put addEventListener on `body` and then check what the original element was in the event object

Answer (score 0):

use below code. dynamically created element dose not fire event using 'click' function. you need to Attach the handler to the document( body )

```
 $(document).on('click','#standardBox',function(){
   $('#container').html('<div id="newBox"></div>');
   // register event handler for new element created
 });

 $(document).on('click','#newBox',function(){
       $('#container').html('<div id="standardBox"></div>');
    // but this #standardBox has no click event listener
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are writing such complex code to do it. As there can be a very simple code.

Lets say this your html.

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="standardBox"></div>
</div>
```

Now, to change the inner container.

```
$(function(){   
    $('#container div').click(function(){
       $(this).attr("id")=="standardBox"?$(this).attr("id","newBox"):$(this).attr("id","standardBox");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is probably a correct answer to a different question. Thanks.

Comment: @KayaToast : seems you were looking for a solution on a different link. :D :P